# bash: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory | Trying to install Ory

Tags: bash, ssh, server, terminal

I want to install Ory Kratos in my host/server using terminal (cPanel). Being **a complete noob to Linux & servers**, I just copy pasted [this line](https://www.ory.sh/kratos/docs/install/#linux) to the terminal:

```
$ bash <(curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ory/meta/master/install.sh) -d -b . kratos v0.8.0-alpha.4.pre.0
```

But I get this error:

```
bash: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory
```

What is this error? is it related to the requested URL or my server itself? How can I resolve this?

Comment: What output do you get with `cat <(echo a)`?

Comment: @konsolebox What does this do?

Comment: [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html).  We're testing if your system supports it.

Comment: `cat: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory`

Comment: So I guess there's your answer. Your system doesn't.

Comment: If your `bash` version supports the process substitution, please try `cd /dev; sudo ln -s /proc/self/fd .` then execute the shown bash script.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to host an instance of Ory Kratos, it is probably easiest to use Docker!
Check out this tutorial, I think it should be understandable even for beginners: https://youtu.be/Agc27vpKyY0.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use Docker in my shared Node.js host.